# Using inflate on a filter mask using sculptures, how can I easily select all of the modified faces so I can create a material group

Tags: materials, bezier-curves, sculpting

So basically, I'm trying to engrave a rune onto a sculpture plane, so far I've been able to use mask and inflate to achieve my desired geo, however, I'm looking for an easy to way to select all of the faces I've modified so I can apply a material to it.  I would prefer to be face-level accurate but I'm flexible. <s>And I'm also looking for a way to apply materials to Bezier curves in a similar fashion.</s>

Here's a video about runes using Mask (time is baked in):
https://youtu.be/_ETTUwzMkTc?t=683
[image]

Here's an example of what I'm trying accomplish, clean separations, however in my case, more like the 1st image above, using inflation.
https://youtu.be/Y6asaZsDHCg?t=603
[image]

This is the kind of final result I'm going for, note the red inside the groove. (note: this is from Blizzard's OverWatch, one of their hero models in game). 
[image]

<s>Here's a video about using curves:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQrLlJFdwTY</s>

<s>Bonus question, in the video with the masks, first image, is there a way to select just the inner faces that have been recessed?</s>

Comment: It would be better to split your questions into 2 separate posts to maintain the structure of this Q&A site.

Comment: Materials are usually not assigned to sculpted meshes because of the high poly count plus the required UV maps. Better use *Vertex Colors* for sculpts -or- do a retopology of the mesh. Then you have a clean, low-poly mesh to which you can assign materials easily.

Comment: If you want to select the affected vertices, invert the mask so that the rune is masked. Then create a face set from the mask using the menu (*Face Sets > Face Set from Mask*). Then hide everything except the face set (hover the mouse over the face set and press key H). Now when you switch to *Edit* mode, only the vertices of the face set are shown and can be selected with the key A.

Comment: What is the problem when you try to assign a material to a Bezier Curve?

Comment: @Blunder thanks for all of your feedback - the issue that I had with Bezier seemed to be a newb mistake of not being in modeling using look dev.  I assume, no matter how many curves I draw, they are all part of the same curve; this was confusing initially but I think I'll just create more curves to use different materials so that's one question down! Thanks

Comment: @Blunder I guess in general, what's a common flow for applying Materials to a "segments" of a mesh that was created using Sculpture.  I've tried to just select the geo manually, however, since shading smooth is a fake look, I'm getting aliasing on certain diagonals :/  If I were using hard surfacing, I would normally just select my faces and apply a material to it. I'm not familiar with re-topo but I've heard the term, and while in general I know what a vertex is, I'm not sure how that's different than painting a face?  Also, using vertex paint how could I apply materials, aka not just colors?

Comment: @Blunder thank you so much for the face set comment, I just came across a video today about that and I thought it might be useful but at the time it didn't really show how to apply them just create them, thanks for confirming my suspicion, I will take a look at that!

Comment: @Blunder so in summary, I'm just trying to carve out some shapes, and apply different materials to them, eg. in the first image, I'd love to have an outer material and an inner one.  I think the face set will help a lot, though I have aliasing in there, so I'm thinking I just need to do some research on retopo as that might be what I'm after - this is for HP to LP baking for reference.  I was thinking of just sculpting my details and then assigning mats and baking using multires mod. I've been able to bake normals perfectly now it's just diff/occlusion/emission/etc next. Thank you so much!!